# Regular expression to find href attribute of HTML that have image extension

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract all links at images in a document HTML.
Actually I can extract the href attribute value using this RegExp:

```
private static final String HTML_A_HREF_TAG_PATTERN = 
    "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
```

I need to fetch only the link to images, so I have to check, if the string match with images extension (jpg, jpeg, png, gif).

How can I modify my pattern?

Comment: Surely you've tried something?

Comment: Try this (in perl syntax): `href\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))['"]`

Comment: Pls try this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20126/regex-to-get-all-image-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regex similar to this:

```
<[^>]+href\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))['"][^>]*>
```

**Explanation**

`<[^>]+`: open tag that follows by any characters except close tag `>`,

`href\s*=\s*`: text `href` follows by `=` symbol,

`['"]`: open string symbol `'` or `"`,

`([^'"]+.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))`: string composes of any characters except `'` or `"` with image extension,

`['"]`: close string symbol `'` or `"`,

`[^>]*>`: any possible string until close tag.

This quite similar to your regex, I'm not sure that this one can work nicely with Java or not but I tried to test it on online Java regex tester already.

Comment: Even for a regex the use of `[^>]` alone is a poor way to do it. Matches `<!-- href = 'abc.png' -->` but not `<tag attr = '>' href = 'abc.png'>` Might as well not even try to do tag parsing.

Comment: `<(?!\!--)[^>]+href\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))['"][^>]*>` might be help.

Answer (score 3):

Please refrain from using regular expressions to extract data from HTML. You'll find plenty of [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) why on this site.

In your case, you could use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to go through the HTML source of the page and process the required information, as per the below example (adapted from [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)):

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements media = doc.select("[src]");

    Pattern imageExt = Pattern.compile("((jpe?g)|(png)|(gif))$");
    for(Element src : media)    {
        Matcher m = imageExt.matcher(src.attr("abs:src"));
        if(m.find())    {
            System.out.println(src.attr("abs:src"));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - To parse html with regex is *not* recommended!

Although imperfect, this might work. The link is in capture group 2.

```
 # "(?si)<[\\w:]+(?=(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*?(?<=\\s)href\\s*=\\s*(?:(['\"])\\s*((?:(?!\\1).)*?\\.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))\\s*\\1))\\s+(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+>"

 (?si)
 < [\w:]+ 
 (?=
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      (?<= \s )
      href \s* = \s* 
      (?:
           ( ['"] )                      # (1)
           \s* 
           (                             # (2 start)
                (?:
                     (?! \1 )
                     . 
                )*?
                \.
                (?: jpg | png | jpeg | gif )
           )                             # (2 end)
           \s* 
           \1 
      )
 )
 \s+ 
 (?: " .*? " | ' .*? ' | [^>]*? )+
 >
```